# PHP5-GD installation on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: php5-gd

I have problem with php5-gd. When I enter

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

from terminal, I get this line:

```
Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5) but 5.3.6-6~dotdeb.1 is to be installed.
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the dotdeb repo from your system...  It is intended for debian, not for ubuntu, and while dotdob generally states that the packages "should work" in this particular instance, it is creating a conflict...

OR, if you absolutely must keep dotdeb, install php-common from the **ubuntu** repo specifically, and **then** install php5-gd

**EDIT:**
Ok, just noticed how old this question is. Still, for anyone else in a similar situation, answer may be helpful, so not deleting it.

Comment: I would just say _never_ use dotdeb on Ubuntu. It's generally unnecessary since Ubuntu has PPAs for virtually everything under the sun.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah. IMHO there is no *legitimate* reason to use dotdeb on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands to update and upgrade all packages at first. Have you removed some update source in the mean time ?

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```